# Can PHPMailer send emails without configuring MacOS mail client on Monterey?

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon, php, monterey, smtp

On a brand new Macbook running Monterey (M1), as PHP was removed by Apple on OS 12, I have removed all "AMP" preinstalled by Apple and installed HomeBrew "AMP" (with PHP 7.4), which is running perfectly.

Now, as I have setup Wordpress for testing purposes, I am attempting to use Wordpress WP_Mail function, which relies on PHPMailer, which in turn uses PHP Mail command. The latter relies on system specific libraries, and I am bit confused about configuring the correct facility, Mail, SendMail, Mailsend....

Digging the Internet, once upon a time you would achieve this through Postfix or eventually setting up an email account in the System settings for [Mail.app](https://mail.app/) , which I would like to avoid, as I only use web mail on browser and hate to have an email client accessing my account.........

In conclusion, on a Monterey M1 machine, Homebrew "AMP" scenario, is there a way to allow PHPMailer to work, avoiding using [Mail.app](https://mail.app/) account?

Comment: Normally, Wordpress is for websites and the WP_Mail function is for the Wordpress install to leverage the server Wordpress is installed on to send things like password resets or newsletters. What is it you are trying to do exactly with a local install of Wordpress?

Comment: I have installed Wordpress on the Macbook for testing purposes, running smoothly, but I need to test the password reset functionality which requires sending emails through PHPMailer

Comment: Reformulated my question

Comment: For PHPMailer to work, it must also be installed on the Mac. Once you are sure it is installed, you can test it directly outside of Wordpress (check PHPMailer's Github page: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). When you have confirmed it is working, the only email settings you should need are those within the Wordpress install itself in the admin panel.